C# Event Handler executes too late
I have a C# component that executes the following code:
            IsSwapUserOperationInProgress = true;
            var oldUser = m_currentLoggedUser;
            ValidateSwapUserConditions(userName, password, true);
            Logoff(true);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Logon(userName, password);
            UserSwapped?.Invoke(this, new UserSwappedEventArgs(oldUser, m_currentLoggedUser));
            LoggingComponent.WriteSecurityLog("Swap user operation: old user: " + oldUser.Username + " new user: " + m_currentLoggedUser.Username, "Security Component");
            IsSwapUserOperationInProgress = false;

The Logoff call invokes a UserLoggedOff event.
Another component subscribes to this event and it checks the IsSwapUserOperationInProgress flag in its logic.
The problem is that this second component always sees this flag as false.
The call to IsSwapUserOperationInProgress = false is executed before the handler of the second component is executed.
How can I make the handler execute before the flag is set to false?

You do know that your call to Thread.Sleep just halts your thread for half a second. If the event is serviced on the same thread (likely,  but there's not enough context in your question to tell), the that call doesn't do what you thing it does. Try making your method async and use await Task.Delay instead

Are you sure that IsSwapUserOperationInProgress is only set at the two lines you presented? Is the code maybe executed by multiple threads?
Set a breakpoint directly before the invocation and inspect IsSwapUserOperationInProgress.  You might also want to make IsSwapUserOperationInProgress a property in order to be able to log /trace set operations...
